# How to make a progress bar use an image to show progress instead of using a color in Android

Tags: android, image, progress-bar, drawable

I have a logo image that I would like to use in my progress bar.  Each time an image is downloaded, my progress bar creeps up using a blue bar.  However,  I would prefer that it slowly display my logo image, one bit at a time.  I tried:

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/logo"
```

but that just set the entire progress bar immediately to my image.  I also tried setting it dynamically with:

```
progressBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources()...etc)
```

but this just left me with no view and a black empty space.

Can be done?

Comment: Check this up
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581812/custom-progress-bar-in-android

Answer (score 2):

Create a [ClipDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable.html) and set your progressDrawable in XML to point to that ClipDrawable XML which looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/logo"
    android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left" />
</clip>
```

Then in the onProgress just call `yourDrawable.setLevel(progressAmount)`

Comment: I tried that, but I the app is crashing.  I am getting this error: 07-21 15:14:38.492: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(30806): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.widget.ProgressBar   Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: it shouldn't crash, it's exactly the same as `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/logo"` except the drawable is a ClipDrawable...

Comment: Well, I am using <ProgressBar android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_clip"... with the <clip> exactly as you have it above, but with the reference to my drawable.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you set your progress bar to be horizontal, like this: style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"

Comment: I have it set like this: style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal".

Comment: Here's my gist, this works for me: https://gist.github.com/5c08cd2e99b1b572b497/83a00627dc68862b2c25aa27fc1ad346ad41ac6e

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources()...etc)
```