# Android. How to create custom progress bar dialog? Picture attached

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to create such a dialog to show progress bar like I have attached. I want to show some sequence of pictures while some work is doing in background and progress bar is showing to the user. How can I make such a activity/dialog? Can anyone advice me something?

[image]

Comment: This example look similar to what you want to do: [here](http://huuah.com/android-progress-bar-and-thread-updating/) .

Got it from this thread [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581812/custom-progress-bar-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize the ProgressBar ui element.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Your layout would look something like below.

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     ... >
     <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ..... />
     <ProgressBar
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Then in your activity, while your updating the progress bar in the "onProgressUpdate" of an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) you can also switch out the image in the imageView, on some kind of interval.

Answer (score 1):

What's exactly your problem? The layout or the code that shows the different images depending on the progress?

I guess its not the layout. So I would recommend you to use a Runnable / AsyncTask with a Handler. See the [AsyncTask Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for this.

So the main idea would be: Start a dialog in your Main Activity and a Runnable which receives a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) from your main activity. The Runnable itself extends AsyncTask and does something in the "doInBackground" function for example sending messages to your progress dialog through the Handler.sendMessage(msg) function, your main class can receive this messages through the "handleMessage" function and update the image depending on the message received.
That's maybe no the most precise explanation, but the links above should make it clear.