# android display an image when loading url in webview

Tags: android

I have an Android apk which starts webview and loads an url. Since it usually takes time to load the url, how can I display an image when the apk is loading? The image can be a logo, for example.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hope this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581812/custom-progress-bar-in-android

Answer (score 0):

use layout like this

```
 <RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView> //with log
    <WebView>
    <RelativeLayout>
```

When page loads Webview came in front of ImageView. or you can also hide it after page load.

Comment: How do i manage this from the activity? –      
  
`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.loadUrl("http://......") //how to load the image meanwhile? }`