# How can we use custom progress bar with image in android

Tags: android, progress-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom Progress Bar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581812/custom-progress-bar-in-android)

[image]

How can we use image with in progress bar like used in that a bucquet image marked by red rectangle.
Please provide me some code for customizing progress bar and use image in that

Comment: Have you googled yourself for an answer? You haven't mentioned your effort so far. Here some posts I found:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581812/custom-progress-bar-in-android
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020882/how-to-change-progress-bars-progress-color-in-android

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the `thumb` image of the `progressBar` moving with the progress then you can you a `seekBar` and define the `thumb` image like this

```
 <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progress="50"
            android:thumb="@drawable/icon"
             />
```